# Evaluating triple integrals that are bounded

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm slowly learning how to bound triple integration problems, but this one has me a little confused.

$\iiint_D(x+2y)dV$, where D is bounded by the parabolic cylinder, $y = x^2$, and the planes x=z, x=y, and z=0, we must evaluate the integral.

So, I will turn this into cylindrical coordinates.

For z, $0 \leq z \leq rcos\theta$ ( the equivalent of x) because of the planes that slice through the graph, setting boundaries.

For $\theta$, I would think that it is 0 to 2$\pi$ because of the parabolic cylinder.

Finally, for r, I'm not sure where to go. We haven't used the given equation x=y yet either. Is there something I'm missing the point of?

Thank you in advance! I appreciate it.

Comment: A first you have project volume to $xy $ plain and find the region in polar coordinate so determine the bounds of $r$ and $\theta$ and then calculate the bounds of $z$.

Comment: @Ali I've done that, and I end up with a parabola opening upwards, with the line y=x protruding through it. I'm assuming that the bounds we're talking about here are from (0,0) to the point where y=x^2 and y=x intersect? That seems like the only logical option to me...

Comment: That is ok. $\theta$ change from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $r$ change between $0$ and $\frac{\sin\theta}{{\cos^2\theta}}$ . Now you find only the change of $z$ don't forgot the Jacobian in polar coordinate.